# Yield and sections in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

In laravel, you can write the following code so that each time a page loads it will only load style-sheets and JavaScript needed for that page. How do I do this in HAML?

Main layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    @yield('head')
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')
    @endsection
</body>
```

Page to be displayed:

```
@extends('layouts.frontend')

@section('head')
    <!-- Fonts START -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700|PT+Sans+Narrow|Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900&amp;subset=all" rel="styleshee  " type="text/css">
@stop

@section('content')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `app/view/layouts/application.html.haml`(or your other layout file)

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    = yield :head
%body
  = yield :content
```

your page to be displayed

```
- content_for :head do
  %link{:href => "http://fonts.googleapis com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700|PT+Sans+Narrow|Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900&amp;subset=all", :rel => "stylesheet", :type => "text/css"}

- content_for :content do
```

Comment: This works only for rails unfortunately, that is where `content_for` is designed.